# Specifying and manipulating columns inside file - shell/bash

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, unix

line in file:

```
aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, Sept 18, 2016 ##:##PM
```

trying to parse it out (desired output) -

```
aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, "Sept 18, 2016 etc..."
```

using unix shell - trying to wrap last two columns in quotes for a date importing process. However, am trying to aim for a specified column approach in case a situation arises where the two columns are internal ie:

```
aaa, bbb, Sept 18, 2016 etc..., ccc, ddd
```

thus outputing:

```
aaa, bbb, "Sept 18, 2016 etc...", ccc, ddd
```

The command to display it is fine - as i can redirect it to a file and work with it from there

Comment: So what *exactly* is the format? If you want to recognize things only with month abbreviations, for instance, specify exactly what the abbreviations can be (in some places it would be `Sep 18` rather than `Sept 18`, and I wouldn't want to provide an answer that guesses wrong).

Comment: will the second column of date always end with AM/PM? and other columns won't end with AM/PM? if so, solution would be simpler

Comment: realistically format wouldnt as much matter? it can vary depending on what file is being dealt with, but its always a combination of two columns, separated by a comma

Comment: Agreed if it was a consistent i had a solution for it but it is a mess, I have a delimiter consistent though

Comment: You don't want to change `aaa, bbb` into `"aaa, bbb"`, after all -- you *only* want to identify the dates. So of course it matters.

Comment: ...or is it any column with literal whitespace?

Comment: Anyhow, if it's inconsistent, you need to extend your examples to show a wide range of the various inconsistent possibilities. Otherwise we can't adequately test our answers.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, concept(s) i have been playing with is that seeing as it is consistently the last two fields in file ive been trying to work with NF:

'awk -F',' '{print "\42"$(NF-1)","$NF}' '

in a way to get the last two columns wrapped in dbl quotes however i cant manage to code the closing quotations and trying to implement it to adjust the file. hope that makes sense

Comment: its outputting what im essentially looking for however its just getting it to edit the entire file and closing quotations

Answer (score 1):

The following works with GNU `sed`, when replacing `##:##` in your sample data with actual digits (and assuming the "etc..." given in your second "example" to match the format from your first one):

```
sed -re 's@ ((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|June|July|Aug|Sept|Oct|Nov|Dec) [[:digit:]]+, [[:digit:]]{4} [[:digit:]]{1,2}:[[:digit:]]{2}[AP]M)([, ]|$)@ "\1"\3 @g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your unix tool for column manipulation is awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=", ";OFS=", "} {$5="\""$5; $6=$6"\""; print $0;}' YOUR_FILE.txt
```

$5 and $6 are the numbers of the columns you need to put " around. If you want to put " before the 5th and after the 7th column, just update the awk expression accordingly.